# How to attract the attention of cross site moderator?

Tags: discussion, support

The site https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/ is young and does not yet have Moderators Pro Tempore.  We have been visited by moderators from other sites with powers at Ebooks, but it has been a while since anyone stopped by.  We have a spam post that is 19 hours old with 11 down votes and I am guessing several flags.

How do we get someone to stop by and do some housekeeping?

Comment: The community should just flag them as spam, not downvote. 6 flags I think and they are gone. Edit: there, done.

Comment: For the record, there are no real "cross-site moderators".  Before the Pro-Tem mods are named, the SE Community Team handles the moderation duties, and they should be checking in reasonably often.  But anything you can do yourselves will usually be faster.

Comment: @Bart When a post is flagged as spam, it is automatically downvotes. So some of these 11 down votes are probably caused by spam flags.

Comment: To add to what @psubsee2003 said, every diamond person you saw on ebooks Meta was an SE employee (Jon and Shog I think so far). Moderators from other sites don't have cross-site mod powers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before pro-tempore moderators are appointed, SE employees usually keep an eye on the site and deal with flags. This typically takes a bit more time than when you have your own mods, but usually they check the flag queue at least once a day. This is not necessarily true on weekends or holidays, though.

Flagging as spam is the correct action in any case as already mentioned in the comments. It will draw the attention of any SE employee visiting the site, and they also automatically delete the post after six flags.

If there is a more serious situation that needs attention on the site and nobody from SE seems to be around, the easiest way to get some attention is to ping any moderator from any site you know in chat. Moderators can usually get hold of someone from SE reasonably quickly.

If it is just spam, another way is to link the spam in a high-traffic chat room you visit. That's often the fastest way to get enough spam votes to remove the posts.